# Unable to remove '.sideicon' in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Why my .sideicon class is not removing?

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>650) {
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/BEYOND-VISION-MOTA-LOGO-WHITE.png");
            $(".sideicon").remove();
        }
        else{
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/BEYOND-VISION-LOGO.png");
            
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you share the entire code? also post the <script> tag which you have used.

Comment: If you want to remove the class then there is a method called removeClass().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>650) {
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/BEYOND-VISION-MOTA-LOGO-WHITE.png");
            $("div").removeClass(sideicon);
        }
        else{
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/BEYOND-VISION-LOGO.png");
            
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: it is a div. How can I find find that specific div here?

Comment: Updated the answer, if it is div then you have to use div.removeClass(yourSelector);

Comment: @AlArefin  please share HTML code as well. (add that in your question)

Comment: it's not working. actually I want to show a specific div after scrolling to 650 and before 650 i want to keep the div hidden. How can I do that?

Comment: ok thanks now its working with $("div").removeClass(sideicon);